# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 - Operation Console user configuration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have created users for various roles of MobileFirst Operation Console as below.

- worklightadmin as wladmin
- worklightdeployer as wldeployer
- worklightmonitor  as wlmonitor
- worklightoperator as wloperator

In WAS, mapped these users to Worklight_Administration_Console --> Security role to user/group mapping, respective roles.

Restarted the WAS server. Tried to login to the MobileFirst Operation Console.

Successfully login but getting this message

> You are not authorized to perform this operation.

I am not sure what other setting need to be configure. If i login using WAS IBM Console admin userid and password, i am able to see all the runtime.

Comment: Actually, i missed to map the users and group to WorkLight_Administrator_Services application in WAS. Once added its started working fine.

Comment: Please supply the above as an Answer to the question instead of a Comment.

Comment: why are you not responding?

Comment: Hi Idan, Sorry i have a bad injury in my foot. Just checked this online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Actually, i missed to map the users and group to
>   WorkLight_Administrator_Services application in WAS. Once added its
>   started working fine.